# JavascriptMVC and JQuery

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, jquery

I was put in charge of managing and enhancing a JavascriptMVC framework that works with python for the backend.  I am more of a backend developer, but need to try to expedite some front end features.

Having dealt with jquery in the past, I thought I could apply some changes onto the DOM after it had loaded.  Here is what I tried...

I did try to apply a raw jquery script directly to the end of the index.html page (and after the steal call).
I also tried to rap it into the main steal(); call in an init.js script.
Then attempted to place it in the section in question to be altered as a $.Controller .

Obviously this did not work.

My question: How should I inject jquery into the DOM after its been rendered?

Comment: Make sure jQuery is included in your page. Then once your page is loaded and all that, you can write custom code in Chromes Console. So that is possible. If you are trying to bind event listeners in JS, then you would have to use `$('.item').live('click', function(){..})` or `$('.item').on('click', 'a', function() {..});` - Apologies if this is a little off topic.

Comment: Why on God's green earth would you want to "inject jQuery into the DOM after it's been loaded?" What optimization are you after? Like @JREAM said: Just make sure that jQuery is included on the page.

Comment: @JREAM: Thank you very much for the comment.  I will definitely need to try both of those.

Comment: @JimG.: I know, I know.  If I had the time trust me I would just pounding away at reverse engineering this beast, however I need band aids like a shark victim right away.  I can't get into too much more details other than to say that it has been build over the last year by approx 5 people and has a lot of moving parts and special requirements.

Comment: @JREAM: forgot to mention, that jquery is being included on every section that I have looked into.

Comment: Is your question about the [tag:javascriptmvc]?

Comment: yep.  I basically want to know if there is a way to apply jquery to a rendered javascriptMVC page.

Comment: I am sure this is possible somehow; however I did dive into the framework enough to figure out how to edit it from the inside out.  The controllers and CSS for the mixture of look and behavior can become so convoluted in these frameworks.  thanks for all the comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just learned the scheme that the previous people had created in this framework.  It was quicker than I thought, but still painful and more to come.